# Automate commands in git cmd?

Tags: c#, git, command, command-line-interface

Is there a way to automate input in git-cmd without actually typing in the input command? Let's say write the input to a script to run automatically?

1. start git.cmd
2. connect to git server.
3. clone git repository.
4. input password.

Comment: Yes. They're called batch files. There are literally thousands of examples here of using them. Search for `batch file`.

Comment: will it work for git-cmd?

Comment: I might be wrong, but if you are using Windows, maybe you could add git to the environment variables, and create a Windows Service or use the Windows Task Scheduler to perform some operation on the windows cmd.

Comment: What is this `git-cmd` that you keep referring to?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by git-cmd.  There is a command file installed with MSysGit (git.cmd) which launches Git.  There is also the bash terminal that typically is installed with Git.  Which git-cmd are you talking about?

Comment: I don't know. Your question said nothing about `git-cmd` when you posted it. Perhaps if you took the time to write a more specific question, someone here might be able to help you find an answer. As it's written now, the question is pretty vague. Please [edit] to provide more detail about precisely what you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara i'm taking about the git-cmd you get with install Git. Yes i do have the git.cmd, and that's the one i'm talking about. updated post.

Comment: @nwinkler i'm talking about he git-cmd you get with installing Git. there are git-bash, git-cmd, git-gui

Comment: @KenWhite updated post.

Answer (score 2):

I have this exact same situation and I automated it using [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 600
log_user 0

spawn git clone http://myuser@myserver/group/repo.git tmp/repo

expect "Password for 'http://myuser@myserver':"
send "mypassword\r"
expect eof
```

Key was setting `timeout` appropriately.

I see that [expect for Windows](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.4/expect4win/) is available.

Comment: you can do this in windows cmd?

Comment: updated my answer to point to the [Windows-specific implementation of expect](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.4/expect4win/)

Comment: I tried the above script in my .bat file, i'm getting error saying first three lines are not internal or external commands. @Wolf

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "git-cmd" is the Windows command shell setup for Git then all you need to do is write a command script (or batch file).  You can find general instructions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file).  It is worth noting that the Git bin folder will need to be in your path.  The Git command to clone a repository is described [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).  As was mentioned in another answer you could write a program to spawn a command shell and run the command script, but that seems the long way around.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, but when i get prompt a password to get into git server, how would i go about adding a script to automatically add input?

Comment: Now that we know what the question actually is I think Wolf has a good answer.